# High query response time for find operation in mongo 4.0.27 with mmap storage engine

Tags: mongodb, performance-testing, database-performance

**Scenario:**

We have application which is doing CRUD operations on database. For past 2 years we have been using mongo 3.6.9 and system has been working fine without any issues. When we upgraded the database from 3.6.9 to 4.0.27, we started getting high query response time for find operation but it is not consistent in nature. Sometimes we are getting high query response in 5 hours or 7 hours or even 11 hours.

**Testing environment:**

- java client driver on application side - 3.12.9
- mongo version - 4.0.27
- Storage Engine - mmap
- Replica-set: 7 members (4 non-arbiter and 3 arbiter, all voting members)

*One of the member CMD as an example:*

```
mongod --keyFile=/mongodb.key --storageEngine mmapv1 --nojournal --noprealloc --smallfiles --ipv6 --bind_ip_all --port 27035 --dbpath=/mmapv1-tmpfs-27035 --replSet rs-app_shardAB-ipv6-7 --quiet --slowms 500 --logpath /data/db/mongo-27035.log --oplogSize 3221 --setParameter diagnosticDataCollectionEnabled=true --logappend --logRotate reopen
```

**Messages:**
As a sample, we got these kind of messages on mongo secondary logs given below:

> 2022-02-02T02:55:54.392+0000 I COMMAND [conn554] command drasessions_1.drasessions command: find { find: “drasessions”, filter: { _id: { sessionid: “ClpGx3:172.16.241.40:15124:1643368779:0080300316” } }, limit: 1, singleBatch: true, $db: “drasessions_1”, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1643770525, 464), signature: { hash: BinData(0, A9E0739EB1E3BBA9EF776A9FCEC9342E9457D221), keyId: 7042384422720503811 } }, lsid: { id: UUID(“8b321501-be08-4fa8-ada5-367cc1eb555e”) }, $readPreference: { mode: “nearest” } } planSummary: IDHACK keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:239 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 }, acquireWaitCount: { r: 1 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { r: 28911648 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 1 } } } **protocol:op_msg 28911ms**

**Troubleshooting performed so far:**

- We have already checked network latency/CPU/RAM/disk space on VM and blade level, so there was no issue also we tested mongo 3.6.9 in same environment and configuration but there is no issue observed.
- We enabled mongostat and also attached it as a reference and found below suspect point:
- For one of the secondary there are no CRUD operation for 26 sec (*0 *0 *0 *0 in mongostat observed), then suddenly high CRUD operation(*2444 110 *5781 *1816 in mongostat observed) were found on that secondary, there is no connection lost message found in mongostat for that secondary. This pattern is common whenever we are getting high response time (28 sec) on that secondary.

**Additional Observation:**

For Primary it is always showing *0 for insert operation for all the time but on secondary’s replication is happening for insert like given below:[*Mongostat output in rawformat given below: can look into table format snapshot for more clarity*]

**host insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped vsize res faults qrw arw net_in net_out conn set repl time**

```
[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:59]:27032 *245 36 *595 *155 0 65|0 0 6.63G 4.49G 0 0|0 0|0 24.9k 124k 144 rs-app_shardAB-ipv6-4 SEC Feb 3 17:06:46.063
[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27032 *0 *0 *0 *0 0 63|0 0 6.61G 4.49G 0 0|0 0|0 11.3k 71.9k 184 rs-app_shardAB-ipv6-4 SEC Feb 3 17:06:46.068
[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:b]:27032 *227 40 *589 *155 0 64|0 0 6.75G 4.48G 0 0|0 0|0 26.6k 157k 144 rs-app_shardAB-ipv6-4 SEC Feb 3 17:06:46.075
[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:c]:27032 ***0** 39 827 150 68 119|0 0 6.79G 4.49G 0 0|0 0|0 592k 1.49m 371 rs-app_shardAB-ipv6-4 PRI Feb 3 17:06:45.627
localhost:27032 *0 41 795 162 70 120|0 0 6.79G 4.49G **0** 0|0 1|0 589k 1.50m 371 rs-app_shardAB-ipv6-4 PRI Feb 3 17:06:47.584
```

[image: Above output in table format]

**Queries:**

- There is no CRUD on one of the secondary for 26 sec when there is no connection lost between primary and secondaries,
- Always 0 insert operation is showing in Primary in mongostat and even replication for insert is happening on secondaries.
- This behavior is not observed in 3.6.9 where same configuration and environment was used.

**Attachments:**

***Mongostat:*** From 26 sec we observer 0 CRUD values for [2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27032 and suddenly it got increased and there is no connection issues between members.

Mongostat showing zero value for CRUD for [2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27032

[image]

Mongostat showing zero value for CRUD for [2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27032

[image]

Mongostat showing sudden high  value for CRUD for [2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27032

[image]

**rs.status output from one of the member:**

```
rs-app_shardAB-ipv6-8:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "rs-app_shardAB-ipv6-8",
        "date" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.647Z"),
        "myState" : 2,
        "term" : NumberLong(33),
        "syncingTo" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27040",
        "syncSourceHost" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27040",
        "syncSourceId" : 3,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(300),
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1643977358, 530),
                        "t" : NumberLong(33)
                },
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1643977358, 526),
                        "t" : NumberLong(33)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1643977358, 589),
                        "t" : NumberLong(33)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                }
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:c]:27040",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 12732,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1643977358, 464),
                                "t" : NumberLong(33)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.560Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.526Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(40),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncingTo" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27040",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27040",
                        "syncSourceId" : 3,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 10
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:b]:27040",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 12732,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1643977358, 252),
                                "t" : NumberLong(33)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.308Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.479Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(40),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncingTo" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27040",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27040",
                        "syncSourceId" : 3,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 10
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "name" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27040",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 12732,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1643977358, 526),
                                "t" : NumberLong(33)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.538Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.507Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(40),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncingTo" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1643964608, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2022-02-04T08:50:08Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 10
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 4,
                        "name" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:a9]:27040",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 7,
                        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                        "uptime" : 12732,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.608Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.569Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(20),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncingTo" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 10
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 5,
                        "name" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:b9]:27040",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 7,
                        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                        "uptime" : 12732,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.644Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.396Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(20),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncingTo" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 10
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 6,
                        "name" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:bc]:27040",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 7,
                        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                        "uptime" : 12732,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.574Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38.430Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(75),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncingTo" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 10
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 7,
                        "name" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:59]:27040",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 12734,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1643977358, 589),
                                "t" : NumberLong(33)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-02-04T12:22:38Z"),
                        "syncingTo" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27040",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "[2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:60]:27040",
                        "syncSourceId" : 3,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 10,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1643977358, 589),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1643977358, 595),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"B/K0J5a7Pl3Ht0ZZ9/ETQ3Ri29M="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("7042384439900372995")
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: How the collection looks like and indexes? It seems you dont have such  field in your collection ( keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 )

Comment: collection indexes:
rs-app_shardAB-ipv6-8:SECONDARY> db.drasessions.getIndexSpecs() [ { "v" : 2, "key" : { "systemId" : 1, "nextEvalTime" : 1 }, "name" : "systemId_1_nextEvalTime_1", "ns" : "drasessions_1.drasessions" }, { "v" : 2, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "drasessions_1.drasessions" } ]

Comment: { "_id" : { "sessionid" : "ABCD" }, "ts" : NumberLong("1643809645651"), "srk" : "static_srk", "originHost" : "static_consumer-vPAS_client1-claiper.pcef", "originRealm" : "calipera", "destHost" : "static_consumer-vPAS_server1-claiper.pcrf", "destRealm" : "caliperb", "apn" : "ims.com", "imsi" : "55500004931012", "ipv6" : "4446:7903:1853:3dc4", "msisdn" : "2224931011", "nextEvalTime" : ISODate("2022-02-08T03:00:21.190Z"), "staleSessionExpiryCount" : 6, "staleBindingRefreshTime" : ISODate("2022-02-04T13:27:25.651Z"), "sessionid" : "ABCD", "systemId" : "fpas-system-1", "uuid" : "fpas-system-A" }

Comment: It looks like you need to create  index on _id.sessionid ...

Comment: What is collection size and RAM?

Comment: Another question: why you dont switch to WiredTiger? (mmap is going deprecated soon)

Comment: Also timeAcquiringMicros: { r: 28911648 } -> very big , your query has to wait for the lock to be released ...

Comment: To me it looks now is the time to switch to wiredTiger to gain advantage of document locking(wiredTiger) over collection locking (mmapv1)

Comment: also what is the output from: db.printReplicationInfo() , it looks your SECONDARY delay abit ? And mongotop ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Init sync your members one by one to wiredTiger. ( this will boost your performance due to the document locking & multithreding and will get rid of the annoying mmapv1 space preallocation issue where you need to init sync from time to time to optimize the storage utilization  )
2. Your query is not using index , since sessionid is nested field in _id,
   to get advantage of the default _id index better you insert the sessionId directly in the _id , otherways you need to created one more index :

   ```
    db.drasessions.createIndex({"_id.sessionid":-1})
   ```

but this is not recommended since you already have the default index on _id